# Isomorphism of graded algebras

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $A$ and $B$ be two graded commutative algebras over $\mathbb C$ such that the affine varieties Spec(A) and Spec(B) are isomorphic. Is it true that the graded algebras $A$ and $B$ are isomorphic as well ?

Comment: Do you mean isomorphic as graded algebras or as algebras with grading forgotten?

Comment: Yes, I mean isomorphic as graded algebras. Thanks.

Comment: This is trivially false: take $A=\Bbb C[t]$ with the trivial grading ($\deg =0$ for all elements), and $B=\Bbb C[t]$ with the standard grading having $\deg t=1$. The rings are isomorphic, so they have isomorphic spectra, but they are not isomorphic as graded rings since $A$ has noninvertible elements of degree zero but $B$ does not.

Comment: Note that you're just asking if an isomorphism of commutative algebras preserve the grading of graded algebras which of course must not be the case. (This is basically what KReiser used.)